# Cannot Access Internal Site When Connected to OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ip

I am connected to my work's network and connected to my home office local network.  I am unable to access an internal-facing site via typing in the URL browser address bar 10.0.0.5.  This did work a couple times previously.  I did notice that my local home office network has 10.0.0.1 set up as access to the router on the network.  Any thoughts?  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is almost certainly that your office VPN lies in the same network as your home one (10.0.0.0/??). There is no trivial solution, but if your home network is simple and you dont have any static ips - or can change these -you could change your home router to another range. 192.168.1.x is a typical choice.

You can also approach your works IT department and -in a politer way then I'm saying it - advise they are tools for putting a VPN on 10.0.0.x - any competent administrator would know to put it on something more specific and less likely to conflict with a fair percentage of remote systems.

Comment: I really appreciate and this was exactly the situation.  I enabled my mobile hotspot on my cell phone, which may be coincidentally that I also bought a new phone with the same service, and I was able to connect to the internal sites with the VPN finally with OpenVPN.  I also adjusted the Settings in the OpenVPN app to use seamless connections/Seamless Tunnel.  This seems to me to be the most secure, too, along with it working.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the subnets are overlapping is a big indicator that a local device with the same ip (.5) is responding faster then a device on your work's side. This can be solved in multiple ways

- Changing the local subnet to another unused subnet, which is better to be using a 192.168 subnet, in the case that other subnets (i.e. 10.0.10.1/24) is used at work.
- Changing the OpenVPN tunnel from split-tunneling to redirecting the traffic through the VPN tunnel. This can be done by adding `redirect-gateway` to the .ovpn config file that is stored on your local machine.